# Insert the data in custom table in wordpress plugin

Tags: database, jquery-ui, wordpress

I am trying to insert the data but getting fatal error i am seding from script ajax call .Please help me some one.Thanks in advance.Am using this for Wordpress plugin development

```
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wordpress/wp-config.php' );
global $wpdb;
$table ='wp_mnggallery';

if(isset($_POST['img'])){

$img = $_POST['img'];
$back_image = $_POST['back_img'];
$url = $_POST['url'];

$data = array(
        'id' => "",
        'images' => "$img",
        'back_image' => "$back_image",
        'url'=>"$url"       
);

$number_images = count($img);
    //Inserting the data
      $q =  $wpdb->insert($table ,$data);

       echo $img.' is updated succefully <br>'; 
}
```

Ajax call for this code sending from another page it was  :

```
<script>
$('#submit').submit(function(event){ 
event.preventDefault();
var img = $('#img').val();
var backimage = $('#back_img').val();
if(img!=''&backimage!=''){
 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '<?php echo plugins_url(); ?>/mngimageeffects/post.php',
      data: $('#submit').serialize(),
      success: function( response ) {
    $('#error').html( response );
$('#mng_img').append('<div class="col-md-4"><img src="'+img+'"width="100%"/></div><div class="col-md-2"><a href="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"><button class="btn btn-primary delete" id="delete">Upload</button></a></div>');
//delete = delete + 1;
   $('#img').val('');
    $('#back_img').val('');
    $('#url').val('');
               }
    });
}else{
    alert('Please Enter The Frent Image and Back Images Urls: ');
}

});
</script>
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Beofore adding this tag fatal eror link : include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wordpress/wp-config.php' );

Comment: But now no  error i found but it was not inserting the data in table why i could not understand.

Comment: the code looks okay, are you sure the table name is correct and the field names are correct?

Comment: Ya sure same table name and fields also same.and i also recheck that the data from my ui to this file succesfully sending only $q =  $wpdb->insert($table ,$data); not working

Comment: is $_POST['img'] set? did you check it?

Comment: Ya i check that one also 3 variables data getting in this page succesfully i am able to see this result by giving echo statement in my ui.

Comment: What i was observed is include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wordpress/wp-config.php' );  ----------- in this link if i replace instead of wordpress my site name saving the data succeefully but it sould be in dynamic for my plugin will u help in this way.  -- Note : I am now checking in local host of wamp server.

Comment: are you inserting data through ajax?

Comment: Ya. if i replace instead of wordpress my site name below the link.include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wordpress/wp-config.php' );

Comment: can you show the ajax part also?

Comment: ya sure this is my ajax call:

Comment: Sorry it shows that too long data wait

Comment: I will sent to step by step please check it :$('#submit').submit(function(event){ 
event.preventDefault();
var img = $('#img').val();
var backimage = $('#back_img').val();
if(img!=''&backimage!=''){

Comment: $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '<?php echo plugins_url(); ?>/mngimageeffects/post.php',
      data: $('#submit').serialize(),
      success: function( response ) {
    $('#error').html( response );
$('#mng_img').append('<div class="col-md-4"><img src="'+img+'"width="100%"/></div><div class="col-md-2"><a href="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"><button class="btn btn-primary delete" id="delete">Upload</button></a></div>');
//delete = delete + 1;

Comment: $('#img').val('');
    $('#back_img').val('');
    $('#url').val('');
               }
    });
}else{
 alert('Please Enter The Frent Image and Back Images Urls: ');
}

});
</script>

Comment: Okay, this is not the right way to use AJAX in wp plugins, I will post as answer

Comment: Please give in right way of sending..data i really thankfull to you. - vidya

Comment: Answer added, please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use AJAX in Wordpress plugins

```
jQuery('#submit').submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault(); 
  var img = jQuery('#img').val(); 
  var backimage = jQuery('#back_img').val(); 
  var url = jQuery('#url').val();

  var data = {
        action: 'submit_data',
        img: img,
        back_img: backimage,
        url : url,
    };
  if(img!=''&backimage!=''){ 
     jQuery.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url: ajaxurl,  // if its front end else use else ajaxurl
        data:data,            
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function( response ) {
            alert(response+'sdfs')
           jQuery('#error').html( response );
           jQuery('#mng_img').append('<div class="col-md-4"><img src="'+img+'"width="100%"/></div><div class="col-md-2"><a href="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"><button class="btn btn-primary delete" id="delete">Upload</button></a></div>'); //delete = delete + 1;
           jQuery('#img').val(''); jQuery('#back_img').val(''); jQuery('#url').val('');
        },
         error  :  function(data){
            alert('Error while deleting.');
            return false;
         }
     });
  }
  else{ alert('Please Enter The Frent Image and Back Images Urls: '); }
```

});

and in the PHP side,

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'submit_data' ); // excutes for users that are logged in. 
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_submit_data', 'submit_data' );     //executes for users that are not logged in. 

function submit_data(){
   global $wpdb;
   $table ='wp_mnggallery';

   if(isset($_POST['img'])){

      $img = $_POST['img'];
      $back_image = $_POST['back_img'];
      $url = $_POST['url'];

      $data = array(
              'id' => "",
              'images' => "$img",
              'back_image' => "$back_image",
              'url'=>"$url"       
      );

      $number_images = count($img);
      //Inserting the data
      $q =  $wpdb->insert($table ,$data);
      echo $img.' is updated succefully <br>'; 
      wp_die();
   }
}
```

The url should be url: `admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )`, if its front end else use `ajaxurl` it will automatically include the necessary files

[check](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply but i am not getting result where it is submited  url: admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) this one . I tryied with this code but it was not working.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)and--I was renamed as admin-ajax.php for php code.

Comment: event.preventDefault();  this is not working reloading page.inside of ajax alert function also not working if i submit the form .

Comment: did you include the php file containing insert code into core file?

Comment: means same page should i incliude

Comment: No check the console if there is any error after submitting the form

Comment: This is the error in consol : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token and  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I was clear alll the errors in the consol and it returning '0' value it is submiting to the wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Comment: Edited the answer check the ajax part and php side and don't forget to include the php file

Comment: Ajax side perfect ., it is submiting wp-admin/admin-ajax.php page . Where do i include php file and which file clear this one finally.

Comment: If you developing a theme copy this php code into functions.php or if it is a plugin create a file name something and include that file into the core plugin file is it sound ok?

Comment: Ya, thank you very much finally i found the result thanking you.

Comment: Hi, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't include the config file but wp-load.php when you want to use WordPress functions outside of WordPress

```
define( 'SHORTINIT', true );

require( '/path/to/wp-load.php' );

// use $wpdb after this
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir giving reply if i place this tag shows error like this:-Warning: require(/path/to/wp-load.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\listings\wp-content\plugins\mngimageeffects\post.php on line 7 and Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/path/to/wp-load.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in

Comment: It thought it was clear that you have to change 'path/to/wp-load.php to your own path. In this case probably `require( '../../../wp-load.php' );`